# Can "defaults write" command line configure the menu bar on macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, defaults

I would really like to use a script to enable these things on macOS High Sierra, by using defaults. I know how to create the script in .bash_profile, as I will use a function for it, and then just run the function in the terminal. However, what I'm missing are the actual strings to enable the following:

- Displaying of Bluetooth icon
- Displaying of Volume icon
- Displaying of battery percentage
- Displaying of full date

Are any of these programmatically settable by using Defaults, and have they changed a great deal between 10.6-10.13?

Ok, based on what IconDeamon said in the comments section for this post, I was able to go and edit `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist` and was able to see a list of menus that I have enabled.

However, this does not necessarily take me to the place I want to go to. Ideally, it'd be good to find a list and be able to solve this. I mean, okay, now, thanks to help on this forum, I know that the ones I wish to display are:

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Script Menu.menu`

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu`

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu`

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/TimeMachine.menu`

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/AirPort.menu`

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/TextInput.menu`

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Battery.menu`

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Volume.menu`

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Clock.menu`

and that the menu can have a `_5` or a `_3` at the end to signify where it should go. But..? It's not exactly a user-writable textfile I can just edit.

Comment: I'll presume you know how to set bash and script this and are looking for the keys (or someone to say on the record - no you can't do this) for a specific version of macOS.

Comment: yep. i'm running osx el capitan but the machine i'm looking to just type "defaults" in (my function name in .bash_profile) is going to be a high sierra.

Comment: Look in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist`.

Comment: thanks @IconDaemon - now i have a list of what _i_ tend to use. but i'm not sure how to use this info for writing on a brand new computer. also, the Battery.menu does not automatically seem to specify percentage.

Comment: The following command will show the Battery Percentage: `defaults write com.apple.menuextra.battery ShowPercent YES; killall SystemUIServer`

Comment: @user3439894 You know, I was unable to get that to work on OS X El Capitan. It seems these get tweaked every once in a while, so I'll try this one on macOS High Sierra and see if that'd work. How odd.

Comment: i was unable to get it to work on osx el capitan, high sierra, or mojave. don't know whats' going on. am currently looking for the mojave solution, of course.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This `defaults write` command will enable several menu-bar icons, including Bluetooth.

```
defaults write com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras -array \
"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/AirPort.menu" \
"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu" \
"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Clock.menu" \
"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Displays.menu" \
"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Volume.menu"
```

*Changes will not take effect until you restart the SystemUIServer*:
 `killall SystemUIServer`

If you want to enable additional items, look in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist` to find the specific name of the menu extra you are seeking.

**Note:** If you attempt to enable a menu extra that you do not have on your machine, the command will get stuck in an endless loop. Some users may not have the `Eject.menu`, for example.

Comment: I'm getting an endless loop of 2018-09-25 00:31:35.052 defaults[48638:10853265] 
Rep argument is not a dictionary
Defaults have not been changed.
2018-09-25 00:31:35.973 defaults[48677:10853403] 
Rep argument is not a dictionary
Defaults have not been changed.
2018-09-25 00:31:36.892 defaults[48715:10853535] 
Rep argument is not a dictionary
Defaults have not been changed.
2018-09-25 00:31:37.807 defaults[48753:10853666] 
Rep argument is not a dictionary
Defaults have not been changed.
with macOS High Sierra. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @esaruoho The command needs to be one line -- if you have extra carriage returns or blank lines in there, that might cause an issue like the one you mentioned.

Comment: I did paste it as one line and got those errors.

Comment: Hi, after removing Eject, I was able to get them all to work. Eject.menu was creating this endless loop :)

Comment: For me, the Clock item would always reappear in the defaults after running killall

Answer (score 5):

In macOS Big Sur, it seems some of the options are set in

```
~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.controlcenter.$hostId
```

and can be set by using the `defaults -currentHost write` command.

Battery percentage is one of them.